# Qt creator integrator ndk android

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk

I have problems with link ndk native to qt creator. Android for x86 Clang qt 5.12.8. What is the problem?
I saw how this is done for Cmake, but I have problems with Qmake

```
This work on Cmake
    find_library( camera-lib camera2ndk )
    find_library( media-lib mediandk )
    find_library( android-lib android )
    find_library( gl-lib GLESv2 ) 
    target_link_libraries( native-lib ${camera-lib} ${media-lib} ${android-lib} ${gl-lib} )
```

```
   My .pro file
   NDKLIB = -L"С:\ndk\21.2.6472646\sysroot\usr\lib\i686-linux-android" \
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libc.a
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libcompiler_rt-extras.a
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libdl.a
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libm.a
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libstdc++.a
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libz.a
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libmediandk.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libnativewindow.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libdl.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libandroid.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libGLESv2.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libstdc++.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libbinder_ndk.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libGLESv3.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libsync.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libjnigraphics.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libvulkan.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libc.so
        LIBS += $$NDKLIB\libz.so
```

```
error: undefined reference to 'ACameraManager_delete'
error: undefined reference to 'ACameraManager_getCameraIdList'
error: undefined reference to 'ACameraManager_getCameraCharacteristics'
error: undefined reference to 'ACameraMetadata_getConstEntry'
error: undefined reference to 'ACameraManager_deleteCameraIdList'
error: undefined reference to 'AImageReader_setImageListener'
error: undefined reference to 'AImageReader_new'
error: undefined reference to 'AImageReader_setImageListener'
error: undefined reference to 'AImageReader_getWindow'
error: undefined reference to 'ACaptureSessionOutput_create'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be linking against `libcamera2ndk` as well?

Comment: I added, but still got an error